# How to redirect to a file from a heredoc

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document

I have this:

```
cat <<EOF

'use strict';

exports.default = {

  'display names': {}

}

EOF >  "$PWD/tmp.js"
```

but this is syntactically wrong apparently, anybody know the syntax to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-heredoc-to-a-file-in-bash-script

Comment: Put the thing on the same line `cat <<EOF > "$PWD/tmp.js"` ... lines ... `EOF`.

Comment: Somewhat similar: [*How can I use a “here document” in the middle of a pipe?*](https://superuser.com/q/1379863/432690)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
cat <<EOF > "$PWD/tmp.js"
'use strict';
exports.default = {
  'display names': {}
}
EOF
```

The here-doc redirection operator (`<<EOF`) is just like other redirection operators, it doesn't end the command. The here-doc itself starts on the following line.

You could also write that first line as `cat > "$PWD/tmp.js" <<EOF` if that makes it seem more logical.